# Adyen Web Drop In

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, adyen

I've gone through most of the instructions here and am able to process a test card transaction https://docs.adyen.com/online-payments/web-drop-in. I pulled down the example repo here https://github.com/adyen-examples/adyen-dotnet-online-payments.

The issue I'm having in the redirect result, the **returnUrl** does not have the **sessionId** or **redirectResult** appended to it as per documentatation. It's just whatever I set it to in the payment request.

So in my controller, the sessions is setting the sessionsRequest.returnUrl = $"https://localhost:44303/Home/Redirect?orderRef={orderRef}":

```
        [HttpPost("api/sessions")]
        public ActionResult<string> Sessions()
        {
            //var hi = new Adyen.
            var sessionsRequest = new CreateCheckoutSessionRequest();
            sessionsRequest.merchantAccount = _merchant_account; // required
            sessionsRequest.channel = (CreateCheckoutSessionRequest.ChannelEnum?) PaymentRequest.ChannelEnum.Web;

            var amount = new Amount("EUR", 1000); // value is 10€ in minor units
            sessionsRequest.amount = amount;
            var orderRef = System.Guid.NewGuid();
            sessionsRequest.reference = orderRef.ToString(); // required
            
            // required for 3ds2 redirect flow
            sessionsRequest.returnUrl = $"https://localhost:44303/Home/Redirect?orderRef={orderRef}";

            try
            {
                var res = _checkout.Sessions(sessionsRequest);
                _logger.LogInformation($"Response for Payment API::\n{res}\n");
                var json = res.ToJson();
                return json;// res.ToJson();
            }
            catch (Adyen.HttpClient.HttpClientException e)
            {
                _logger.LogError($"Request for Payments failed::\n{e.ResponseBody}\n");
                throw e;
            }
        }
```

In the adyenImplementation.js, I have added a console.info to display the session object and looking at the console, the **returnUrl** doesn't append anything.

```
const clientKey = document.getElementById("clientKey").innerHTML;

// Used to finalize a checkout call in case of redirect
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const sessionId = urlParams.get('sessionId'); // Unique identifier for the payment session
const redirectResult = urlParams.get('redirectResult');

// Typical checkout experience
async function startCheckout() {
  // Used in the demo to know which type of checkout was chosen
  const type = document.getElementById("type").innerHTML;

  try {
    const checkoutSessionResponse = await callServer("/api/sessions");
    const checkout = await createAdyenCheckout(checkoutSessionResponse);
    checkout.create(type).mount(document.getElementById("payment"));

  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    alert("Error occurred. Look at console for details");
  }
}

// Some payment methods use redirects. This is where we finalize the operation
async function finalizeCheckout() {
  try {
    const checkout = await createAdyenCheckout({id: sessionId});
    checkout.submitDetails({details: {redirectResult}});
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    alert("Error occurred. Look at console for details");
  }
}

async function createAdyenCheckout(session){
    return new AdyenCheckout(
    {
      clientKey,
      locale: "en_US",
      environment: "test",
      session: session,
      showPayButton: true,
      paymentMethodsConfiguration: {
        ideal: {
          showImage: true,
        },
        card: {
          hasHolderName: true,
          holderNameRequired: true,
          name: "Credit or debit card",
          amount: {
            value: 1000,
            currency: "EUR",
          },
        },
        paypal: {
          amount: {
            value: 1000,
            currency: "USD",
          },
          environment: "test", // Change this to "live" when you're ready to accept live PayPal payments
          countryCode: "US", // Only needed for test. This will be automatically retrieved when you are in production.
        }
      },
      onPaymentCompleted: (result, component) => {
        console.info("onPaymentCompleted");
        console.info("Session::", session);
        console.info(result, component);
        handleServerResponse(result, component);
      },
      onError: (error, component) => {
        console.error("onError");
        console.error(error.name, error.message, error.stack, component);
        handleServerResponse(error, component);
      },
    }
  );
}

// Calls your server endpoints
async function callServer(url, data) {
  const res = await fetch(url, {
    method: "POST",
    body: data ? JSON.stringify(data) : "",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  });

  return await res.json();
}

function handleServerResponse(res, _component) {
    switch (res.resultCode) {
      case "Authorised":
        window.location.href = "/Home/result/success";
        break;
      case "Pending":
      case "Received":
        window.location.href = "/Home/result/pending";
        break;
      case "Refused":
        window.location.href = "/Home/result/failed";
        break;
      default:
        window.location.href = "/Home/result/error";
        break;
    }
}

if (!sessionId) { startCheckout() } else { finalizeCheckout(); }
```

[image]

Any advice please? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You set (correctly) the session request (which you prepare before performing the `sessions` call) with the desired `returnUrl` (i.e. https://localhost:44303/...). At this point there is no interaction with the Adyen platform yet.

Once submitting the `/sessions/` call the drop-in will take care of performing the payment and interacting with the Adyen platform. When the **payment flow requires a second step** (i.e. for iDeal the shopper opens the home banking app) then the shopper is redirected to the `returnUrl` where the `redirectResult` gets appended

```
https://localhost:44303/Home/Redirect?orderRef=123&redirectResult=eyJ0cmFuc1N0YX..
```

In the case of a Credit Card payment (without additional verification step) there is no redirect involved (`returnUrl` is not used).

Comment: How would I get the PSP reference in the case where the payment flow does not require a second step? Can it be done without a Webhook?

Comment: The information is indeed provided by the webhook. Basically, the drop-in implements the logic to perform the payment (after the payment session is created) and the application is notified asynchronously (within a pretty short timeframe anyway)

Comment: I want to avoid using a webhook. Is there any other way of getting the PSPReference by calling another API or something?

Comment: When using the latest drop-in you can still use the previous workflow (before 5.0.0) https://docs.adyen.com/online-payments/web-drop-in/integrated-before-5-0-0 and implement the payment executing `/paymentMethods`, `/payments ` and `/payments/details` (the last one will give you the pspReference)

Comment: It is recommended to use webhook however, as they will always deliver the payment result (even when the shoppers fails to return to your website).  Any technical reason why avoiding webhooks? I can help if needed